# How to convert the predictions I got (shape : (359,3)) into (359,) as different classes?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, one-hot-encoding

I tried building a cnn model to train on the ultrasound image dataset which consists of three classes.

```
data = []
img_size = 256

for i in categories:
    path = os.path.join(directory_train, i)
    class_num = categories.index(i)
    for file in os.listdir(path):
        filepath = os.path.join(path, file)
        img = cv2.imread(filepath, 0)
        # preprocess here
        img = cv2.resize(img, (img_size, img_size))
        data.append([img, class_num])
        
random.shuffle(data)

X_train, y_train = [], []
for feature, label in data:
    X_train.append(feature)
    y_train.append(label)
    
print('X_train length:', len(X_train))
print('y_train counts:', Counter(y_train))

# normalize
X_train = np.array(X_train).reshape(-1, img_size, img_size, 1)
X_train = X_train / 255.0
y_train = np.array(y_train)
print(X_train.shape)
print(y_train.shape)
```

output : X_train length: 1600
y_train counts: Counter({1: 804, 0: 632, 2: 164})
(1600, 256, 256, 1)
(1600,)

I had done the same preprocessing for the test data also.

Before building model I encoded the class variables like below

```
y_train = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train,3)
y_test = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y_test,3)
```

I built model with four convolutional layers and two fully connected layers.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import layers

# Set up the CNN model
#Convolutional Neural Network (CNN) with four convolutional layers and two fully connected layers.
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=X_train.shape[1:]),
    layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)),
    layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
    layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)),
    layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
    layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)),
    layers.Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
    layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)),
    layers.Flatten(),
    layers.Dense(256, activation='relu'),
    layers.Dense(3, activation='sigmoid')
])

# Compile the model
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

I trained the model using the preprocessed data.

```
history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=3,
                    validation_data=(X_test, y_test))
```

I tried predicting the data using :

```
predictions = model.predict(X_test)
predictions
```

I also tried this:

```
predictions.argmax(1)
```

It only returns 2 classes [0 and 1] but my problem have another class as well

but the values in predictions doesn't make any sense and also shape of the predictions is (359,3)

I want my predictions to be [0 or 1 or 2] according to their classes but I found floats in matrix format.

Can anyone help me to find where I was wrong and what should be done to solve this issue?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: why would `(359,3)` would not make sense as shape if you have 0/1/2 as possible classes?

Answer (score 0):

well your predictions being 359 X 3 is probably correct. It means that 359 predictions were made. Each prediction is associate with 3 probability values. The first one p[0][0] is the first prediction and is the probability the image belongs to class 0. p[0][1] is the first prediction and is the probability that the image belong to class 1 and similarly p[0][2] is the probability that the image belongs to class 2. Now you want to select the index of p that has the highest probability. You can use np.agrmax to find that index and its value is the predicted class of the image.
The code below will process the predictions and print the class for each prediction.

```
preds=model.predict(etc)
for i, p in enumerate(preds):
    klass=np.agrmax(p)
    print i, klass
```

Comment: Now I understood the thing here.